# Android service to monitor click events

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

I've just started getting into Android development and as a proof of concept I am tasked with creating a click logging system for several applications. These applications may be written by other teams within my organization or may very well be any application downloaded from Google Play.

So is it possible to create a service that monitors every click event from any application running? Any type of global onClick Listener?

If so, any pointers in the right direction would be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding a transparent view to the global window manager, same place toast messages are added. Then you can just intercept touch events via by overriding the onInterceptTouchEvent() method on any viewGroup and passing the event down.

Many apps have a similar approach (AnyDo is one of the apps that add a view in this manner, Facebook Home as well).

Answer (score 0):

> So is it possible to create a service that monitors every click event from any application running? Any type of global onClick Listener?

Fortunately, not on Android 4.0+, for obvious privacy and security reasons. Such a "tapjacking" attack was possible on earlier versions of Android.

Comment: If the app is a System app and/or runs as root, is it possible to perform any kind of "tapjacking" then?